# Reaching a specific item in define-struct

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm really stuck about somethings and I will try to tell my questions correctly, I hope you can understand. It can be a little bit long so firstly thank you to spends your time to read this.

I'm trying to create a game whose name is "Same" in Racket 5.0.2 version.

Here is explanation of the game: http://download.racket-lang.org/docs/5.0.2/html/games/same.html?q=games

I created a table with disks and draw it:

```
a: width
b: height
r: radius

    (define (color x)  ///for random colors
      (cond [(< (random x) 100) 'blue]
            [(< (random x) 200) 'purple]
            [(< (random x) 300) 'yellow]
            [(< (random x) 400) 'red]
            [else 'green]))

    (define-struct top (coord color))
    (define (row x y)
      (if (> x (- a r)) empty
          (cons (make-top (make-posn x y)(color 500)) (row (+ x (* 2 r)) y))))

    (define (draw-row L)
      (if (empty? L) #f
          (and
            (draw-solid-disk (top-coord (first L)) r (top-color (first L)))
            (draw-row (rest L)))))

    (define (board x y)
      (if (> y (- b r)) empty
          (cons (row x y) (board x (+ y (* 2 r))))))

    (for-each draw-row (board 20 20))
```

So I've 200 disks with random colors...(There are 20 disks in every row)

Here my biggest problems are:

**1) To delete the disk, player will input particular line and column. Will I have conditions for every choices?**

```
if line=1 and column=1, delete this disk and its same colored adjacent disks
if line=5 and column=7, delete that disk and its same colored adjacent disks
```

I hope you have some easier, alternative ways because it looks extremely challenging.

**2) How can I compare disk's colors in many lists? It's hard to tell my problem but I'll try.**

```
    (define table (board 20 20))      
    (define row1 (list-ref table 0))
    (list-ref row1 0)
```

It will return:

```
(make-top (make-posn 20 20) 'yellow)
```

How can I reach **'yellow** in here? And if I reach, how can I compare it with other colors?

Any idea would be great! I've been thinking about these questions for 2 days and still I couldn't do anything.

*I shouldn't use mutable structures*

Comment: BTW, your `color` function should call `(random x)` only once and store its value (using a `let` or an internal `define`), and not call `(random x)` multiple times. Thus: `(define (color) (let ((value (random 500))) (cond ((< value 100) 'blue) ((< value 200) 'purple) ((< value 300) 'yellow) ((< value 400) 'red) (else 'green))))`

Comment: You're already using `top-color` and `top-coord` in your code. What makes you think that they wouldn't work for this?

Comment: Also the `color` function shouldn't take an argument. It's weird the caller must supply the magic value `500` in order for the `cond` statement to work. That's a detail `color` should keep to itself. It should probably be renamed `random-color`, too.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young and @GregHendershott, I got it. I took this assignment before learning about `let`. I fixed my code thanks to you.
@molbdnilo, I guess, I couldn't understand `define-struct` but I see everyting clearly now.
Thanks for your comments! If you have an idea about second question, please write it.

Answer (score 3):

Structs come with built in accessors:

```
> (define my-top (make-top (make-posn 20 20) 'yellow))
> (top-color my-top)
'yellow
> (top-coord my-top)
(make-posn 20 20)
> (top? my-top)
true
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I even don't know how I missed this.
However, I still have lots of problems. I have `my-top`, it's ok but I still don't know how I will compare it with its adjacent disks...For example, `if (equal? my-top my-top2) delete them`...I will contain every disks in different variables like `my-top`, `my-top2`, `my-top3`...
I guess I should use `row` list in here but I can't figure out how I will do that.

Comment: Think about representing all of the state with one variable - a simple list  for all the positions on the board (200 elements). This can be cons'd up. Use a helper function that returns the current rows. A list of 20 lists of ten elements. The draw function draws these as rows. Each game play function creates a new 200 element list to serve as the new world state. Games are inherently event driven, so there is a new world state after each function is called. The htdp2/universe teachpack is a good model in Racket.